# Update query is updating and inserting

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to fix the problem for past 2 hours but no luck.

**I have a page where  I am updating ranking. But the problem is when i click submit button its updating the data and inserting new row of same data. I Don't what I am doing wrong. Please HELP!**

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION)) { 
    session_start(); 
}

if(isset($_GET['company']) && isset($_GET['city']) && isset($_GET['state']) && isset($_GET['country'])) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
        $email = $_SESSION['email'];
        $company = $_GET['company'];
        $city = $_GET['city'];
        $state = $_GET['state'];
        $country = $_GET['country'];

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM companies_active_accounts WHERE Company_Name='$company' AND City='$city' AND `State/Province`='$state' AND Country='$country'");

        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM register WHERE email='$email'");
        while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
            $username = $row["username"];
        }

        $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM review WHERE company_name='$company' AND city='$city' AND state='$state' AND country='$country' AND username='$username'");
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result1);

        if(isset($_POST['rating'])) {
            $input1 = $_POST['input-1'];
            $input2 = $_POST['input-2'];
            $input3 = $_POST['input-3'];
            $input4 = $_POST['input-4'];
            $input5 = $_POST['input-5'];

            $sql1 = "UPDATE `review` SET `respectful` = '$input1', `assurance` = '$input2', `tangibles` = '$input3', `empathy` = '$input4', `responsiveness` = '$input5' WHERE company_name='$company' AND city='$city' AND `state`='$state' AND country='$country'";     
            if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
                header('Location:myrating.php');
                exit();
            } 
        }
    }
} else {
    header('Location: '.'index.php');
    exit();
}

?>
<?php include('partials/header.php');?>
<?php include('partials/navbar.php');?>
<!-- Content -->
<section id="review">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <?php  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {  ?>
                    <h1 class="text-center heading" id="a"><?php echo $row['Company_Name'] ?></h1> 
                     <p class="text-center"><span>City: <span id="b"><?php echo $row['City'] ?></span></span> | <span>State/Province: <span id="c"><?php echo $row['State/Province'] ?></span> | </span><span> Country: <span id="d"><?php echo $row['Country'] ?></span></span></p>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if($rowcount > 0) { 
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
                ?>
                        <form method="post" action="edit_rating.php?company=<?php echo $company ?>&city=<?php echo $city ?>&state=<?php echo $state ?>&country=<?php echo $country ?>" id="rating1" >
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><h2 style="padding-right: 60px;"><span class="hint--top hint--medium" aria-label="A company’s ability to perform the promised service dependably and accurately.">Respectful / Integrity</span></h2></td>    
                                    <td>                  
                                    <input id="input-1" name="input-1" value="<?php echo $row['respectful']; ?>" class="rating-loading" data-size="sm" productId=1>
                                    <script>
                                        $(document).on('ready', function(){
                                            $('#input-1').rating({
                                                step: 1,
                                                starCaptions: {1: 'Very Poor', 2: 'Poor', 3: 'Ok', 4: 'Good', 5: 'Very Good'},
                                                starCaptionClasses: {1: 'text-danger', 2: 'text-warning', 3: 'text-info', 4: 'text-primary', 5: 'text-success'}
                                            });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h2><span class="hint--top hint--medium" aria-label="The knowledge, competence and courtesy of employees and their ability to convey trust and confidence."> Assurance </span> </h2></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="input-2" name="input-2" value="<?php echo $row['assurance']; ?>" class="rating-loading" data-size="sm" productId=2>
                                    <script>
                                        $(document).on('ready', function(){
                                            $('#input-2').rating({
                                                step: 1,
                                                starCaptions: {1: 'Very Poor', 2: 'Poor', 3: 'Ok', 4: 'Good', 5: 'Very Good'},
                                                starCaptionClasses: {1: 'text-danger', 2: 'text-warning', 3: 'text-info', 4: 'text-primary', 5: 'text-success'}
                                            });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h2><span class="hint--top hint--medium" aria-label="Physical facilities, equipment and appearances that impress the customer."> Tangibles </span></h2></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="input-3" name="input-3" value="<?php echo $row['tangibles']; ?>" class="rating-loading" data-size="sm" productId=3>
                                    <script>
                                        $(document).on('ready', function(){
                                            $('#input-3').rating({
                                                step: 1,
                                                starCaptions: {1: 'Very Poor', 2: 'Poor', 3: 'Ok', 4: 'Good', 5: 'Very Good'},
                                                starCaptionClasses: {1: 'text-danger', 2: 'text-warning', 3: 'text-info', 4: 'text-primary', 5: 'text-success'}
                                                });
                                            });
                                        </script>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><h2><span class="hint--top hint--medium" aria-label="The level of caring, individualized attention, access, communication and understanding that the customer perceives."> Empathy </span></h2></td>
                                    <td>
                                    <input id="input-4" name="input-4" value="<?php echo $row['empathy']; ?>" class="rating-loading" data-size="sm" productId=4>
                                        <script>
                                            $(document).on('ready', function(){
                                                $('#input-4').rating({
                                                    step: 1,
                                                    starCaptions: {1: 'Very Poor', 2: 'Poor', 3: 'Ok', 4: 'Good', 5: 'Very Good'},
                                                    starCaptionClasses: {1: 'text-danger', 2: 'text-warning', 3: 'text-info', 4: 'text-primary', 5: 'text-success'}
                                                 });
                                             });
                                         </script>
                                     </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td><h2><span class="hint--top hint--medium" aria-label="The willingness displayed to help and provide prompt service."> Responsiveness </span></h2></td>
                                      <td>
                                          <input id="input-5" name="input-5" value="<?php echo $row['responsiveness']; ?>" class="rating-loading" data-size="sm" productId=5>
                                          <script>
                                              $(document).on('ready', function(){
                                                  $('#input-5').rating({
                                                     step: 1,
                                                     starCaptions: {1: 'Very Poor', 2: 'Poor', 3: 'Ok', 4: 'Good', 5: 'Very Good'},
                                                     starCaptionClasses: {1: 'text-danger', 2: 'text-warning', 3: 'text-info', 4: 'text-primary', 5: 'text-success'}
                                                 });
                                             });
                                         </script>
                                     </td>
                                 </tr>
                             </table>  
                             <br>
                         <?php } ?>
                         <button name="rating" id="rating" class="btn btn-success">Update Ratings</button>
                     </form>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                      <h2>Please Review First before editing.</h2>
                  <?php } 
               }?>            
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</section>

<?php include('partials/footer.php');?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#rating").click(function () {
            var company = $('#a').text();
            var city = $('#b').text();
            var state = $('#c').text();
            var country = $('#d').text();
            var input1 = $('#input-1').val();
            var input2 = $('#input-2').val();
            var input3 = $('#input-3').val();
            var input4 = $('#input-4').val();
            var input5 = $('#input-5').val();
            if(input1 > 0 && input2 > 0 && input3 > 0 && input4 > 0 && input5 > 0) {
                $.post('rating.php',{input1 : input1, input2 : input2, input3 : input3, input4 : input4, input5 : input5, company : company, city : city, state : state, country : country});
                $(this).attr("checked");
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                alert('Please Rate all fields');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank You.

Comment: I don't see any INSERT statements in the code you pasted.  Is it possible that `myrating.php` is doing an INSERT ?

Comment: No. myrating.php only has select query

Comment: I copied the above code from review.php and edited it. review.php was inserting and the above code is updating. but there is no link between two pages.

Comment: Then it's likely the bug is not within the code you posted.  A mysql `UPDATE` won't insert, full stop.

Comment: If you are pretty sure that this code is inserting the new raw then there must be any ghost which is doing this all thing

Comment: I might have not closed connection on any page can that cause problem?

Comment: Above code Is of `rating.php`?

Comment: no edit_rating.php

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Well I am not worried about sql injection at the moment i can change that later but I cant fix this problem.

Comment: In the Javascript at the bottom you have `$.post('rating.php',{/*snip*/});` which seems to post to the wrong file. Can that be the problem?

Comment: "I am not worried about sql injection at the moment i can change that later" but in practice you won't. Once you finish this, you'll move on to the next chunk of functionality you need and once everything is done you'll have forgotten you need to fix this.

Comment: @Phoenix, connections are automatically closed when the script completes execution (in the case of a web page, when it's finished creating the response.) So, forgetting to close non-persistent connections isn't causing your issue. http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

Answer (score 0):

Phoenix, I'd try refactoring your code to make it much easier to check for the trouble. Right now, you've got so many intermingled moving parts that it's hard to isolate issues you're having.

First, pull out the setup for sessions and connection into a separate file include:

**setup.php**

```
<?php
// display errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once('connection.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION)) { 
    session_start(); 
}
```

Then, I'd pull the JavaScript into a separate file. Of note, if the JavaScript is loaded at the bottom, after all of the HTML elements you'll be referencing in the code, you won't need to call ready().

**main.js**

```
// original
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#rating").click(function () {
        var company = $('#a').text();

// shorthand
$(function() {
    $("#rating").click(function () {
        var company = $('#a').text();

// no need for ready() check at bottom of page as relevant DOM has loaded
$("#rating").click(function () {
    var company = $('#a').text();
```

Next, you can refactor your checks. For example, isset() accepts multiple arguments:

```
// original
if(isset($_GET['company']) && isset($_GET['city']) && isset($_GET['state']) && isset($_GET['country'])) {

// shortened
if (isset($_GET['company'], $_GET['city'], $_GET['state'], $_GET['country'])) {
```

That said, really, I'd start breaking this code up into smaller functions that can be checked.

**functions.php (or just add to setup.php**

```
...
function sessionHasEmail() {
    return isset($_SESSION['email']);
}

function newPage($page) {
    header('Location: ' . $page);
    exit();        
}

function getVarsSent() {
    return isset($_GET['company'], $_GET['city'], $_GET['state'], $_GET['country']);
}
```

Now, you can shorten much of the code on this page to:

```
<?php
// include other files and functions and start session
require_once('setup.php');
// check for get vars
if (!getVarsSent()) newPage('index.php')
// conditionally query if email session var set
if (sessionHasEmail()) {
    // these queries can be broken up into functions
}
// etc.
```

The idea is to break the code up into manageable sections that are much easier to understand, test, and reuse.

Also, in terms of the DB, you'll probably want to use unique id's for rows and then reference those when you make updates (it's hard to know for sure with the code you've posted.)

Finally, @jory-geerts made two valuable comments. The POST may be causing some trouble in terms of duplicates (hard to know with the code we see.) And, you should start adding security checks now (SQL prepared statements AND GET/POST var validation.) Security doesn't "bolt-on" well, but it serves as a great foundation :)

If you refactor the code and have issues pinned down to a specific section, post an update and I'll try to help.